# jQuery: multiple photo galleries on same page

Tags: jquery, photo-gallery

I'm trying to figure out how to use a jQuery photo gallery multiple times on one page. Most, if not all jQuery galleries out there user an ID to target the main gallery image and replace the attribute.

How can I construct a gallery and only replace the related main gallery image?

```
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="main_view">
        <img src="092519.jpg" alt="Some Image" />
    </div>
    <ul class="thumb">
        <li><a href="092519.jpg"><img src="092519.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="092520.jpg"><img src="092520.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="092521.jpg"><img src="092521.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="092522.jpg"><img src="092522.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="092523.jpg"><img src="092523.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="092524.jpg"><img src="092524.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="092525.jpg"><img src="092525.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="092526.jpg"><img src="092526.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("ul.thumb li a").click(function () {
    var mainImage = $(this).attr("href"); // Find Image Name
    //$(".main_view img").attr({ src: mainImage });
    $(this).closest("div.main_view").hide(); // doesn't work
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Can you put the demo link with the solution?because I also have same requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easiest to go to the group parent, then find the element you want.

```
$(this).parents('.gallery').find('.main_view');
```

Comment: Yes! This is was I was looking for. For some reason, I wasn't using the "parents" function properly. Thank you, Orbling!

Answer (score 0):

That is a simple jQuery selector assuming that `this` is one of the clicked `a` tags:

```
$(this).closest('div.main_view')
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I am using classes... what I'm asking is how to target the "main_view" class of the current clicked thumb.